# How to remove an app from Windows Store / Microsoft Partner Center?

Tags: windows-store

Because of **regulatory/legal** reasons, I **must** remove an app from the Windows Store. Question is, how can an app be removed at Microsoft Partner Center?

The official recommendation seems to be just making the app unavailable, which I did more than two months ago. However, the app is still available, and Microsoft's Partner Center shows contradicting information:

1. `This product is currently unavailable to customers.` is shown at Application Overview.
2. `In the Microsoft Store` is shown right next to the app's last submission.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Of course, the app can still be found and installed. So, how do you actually remove an app from the Windows store? Any advise is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a customer support question about an app store.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you can't completelly remove apps from windows store but you should be able to make them invisble.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27877362/15970306) to pretty much the same question.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, much appreciated! Problem is, the UI has changed and even although the app is marked as removed from store, it can still be found and installed...

Comment: Alright, am not sure in this one but the docs says:
 "Note that any customers who already have the app will still be able to use it and can download it again"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/guidance-for-app-package-management

Comment: I know this isn't really helping, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Deleting an app from Partner Center [is only possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/manage-app-names#delete-app-names) if it was never published, and you remove all pending submissions:

> To completely remove an app from Partner Center (and release all the names you've reserved for that app), click Delete this app from the App overview page. If you have a submission for the app in progress, you'll need to delete that submission first. **Note that if you've already published the app to the Store, you can't delete it from Partner Center (though you can use the Show/hide products functionality on your Overview page to hide it).**

With an app that was previously published, I don’t think there’s anything else you can do other than making it unavailable.